# Running Eve on Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, eve

I was following the instructions for deploying a python flask app to Azure and was able to do that successfully. So I figured, hey, Eve is a flask app, this should be a piece of cake! I changed the requirements.txt to have eve as a dependency, added settings.py, and updated my main.py.

main.py:

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET','PUT','DELETE']
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET','POST']

X_DOMAINS = '*'
X_HEADERS = ['Content-Type','Location','If-Match']
X_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Content-Type','Location']

setup = {
    'allow_unknown': True
}

DOMAIN = {
    'setup': setup
    }
```

This runs and works locally, so my expectation was that, since Eve is a Flask app, this would work.

I'm working on getting the exception logs, but apart from that, does anyone have a way to get Eve working on Azure?

UPDATE:
Logging was turned on, and the 500 (internal server error) I was getting before produced the following from IIS:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    Python FastCGI
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      https:[webservernamehere]:80/handler.fcgi/
Physical Path      D:\home\site\wwwroot\handler.fcgi\
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

Comment: What isn't working? You've shown no errors or anything. So... not quite sure what can be said...

Comment: I finally have some error logs, I'm getting a 500 internal server error. The 'detailed' information provided by IIS are:

Detailed Error Information:
Module    FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    Python FastCGI
Error Code    0x00000000
Requested URL    https:[webservernamehere]:80/handler.fcgi/
Physical Path    D:\home\site\wwwroot\handler.fcgi\
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous

Comment: Please - don't post this type of info as a comment. This should be part of your question. Please edit your question, and post your (formatted) log information in your question.